# Python - Binary tree - unable to print the tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I have just started programming in Python so be aware that I may have missed something basic.I have tried to make my first binary tree in Python3 and everything seems fine. Next step was trying to print my tree (inorder) but doing this just results in two blank spaces. Any thoughts where I have made a mistake?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, newvalue):
        self.left=None
        self.right=None
        self.newvalue=newvalue


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def put(self, newvalue):
        self.root=puter(self.root, newvalue)


    def write(self):
        writer(self.root)
        print("\n")

def writer(root):
    if root != None:
        writer(root.left)
        print(root.newvalue) 
        writer(root.right)


def puter(root, newvalue):
    if root == None:
        root = Node(newvalue)
    else:
        if newvalue < root:
            if root.left != None:
                puter(newvalue, root.left)
            else:
                root.left=Node(newvalue)
        else:
            if root.right !=None:
                puter(newvalue, root.right)
            else:
                root.right = Node(newvalue)



tree = Tree()
tree.put("bird")
tree.put("snake")
tree.put("lion")
tree.put("elephant")
tree.put("snail")
tree.write()
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple things wrong. You were not returning root in `puter` like kfx mentioned. But your input arguments to `puter` were backwards, `puter(newvalue, root.right)` should be `puter(root.right, newvalue)` and `puter(newvalue, root.left)` should be `puter(root.left, newvalue)`. This code prints the tree:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, newvalue):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.newvalue = newvalue


class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def put(self, newvalue):
        self.root = puter(self.root, newvalue)


    def write(self):
        writer(self.root)
        print("\n")

def writer(root):
    if root != None:
        writer(root.left)
        print(root.newvalue)
        writer(root.right)


def puter(root, newvalue):
    if root == None:
        root = Node(newvalue)
    else:
        if newvalue < root:
            if root.left != None:
                puter(root.left, newvalue)
            else:
                root.left=Node(newvalue)
        else:
            if root.right !=None:
                puter(root.right, newvalue)
            else:
                root.right = Node(newvalue)
    return root


tree = Tree()
tree.put("bird")
tree.put("snake")
tree.put("lion")
tree.put("elephant")
tree.put("snail")
tree.write()
```

Comment: Fantastic, I see where I made the mistakes. Thanks a bunch for the help, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value from `puter` function.

```
 def puter(root, newvalue):
    ...
    return root
```

Otherwise your `root` member gets assigned the default return value, which is `None`.

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that one. Thanks!